# PHP link security

Tags: php, mysql, security

I've a newssystem with a link `index.php?article=news&id=10` and I work also with comments `mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM news_comments WHERE news_id = '10'");`

But when I change the link for example to `index.php?article=news&id=10=asd` the comments are not there, because I added the `asd` at the end.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: delete `=asd` from the url?

Comment: Of course I can do it, but you know, I want to have a system, which can't be manipulated by other people.

Comment: All systems on the web can be manipulated by other people. If someone messes up the URL such that it doesn't return meaningful data anymore, return an error message or a 404. What you have there is a malformed query string - the data your script needs isn't there anymore because you messed with the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to ensure the value of "id" is an integer.

Not sure what your code looks like, but do something like:

```
$id = intval($_GET['id']);
mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM news_comments WHERE news_id = '$id'");
```

You are sanitizing your input as well correct?

Answer (score 0):

`index.php?article=news&id=10&comments=asd` will solve the pb if your code looks like 
 `$id = intval($_GET['id']);
mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM news_comments WHERE news_id = '$id'");`